# EKS upgrade issue

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

We are having multiple issues while upgrading the eks cluster from 1.21 to 1.22. anyone can help me answer the queries?
we have PDB with 1 pod unavailable.
we have node group updateConfig is 30% of max unavailable nodes.
While upgrading the clusters from 1.21 to 1.22 through Terraform we see the error
Error message: Reached max retries while trying to evict pods from nodes in the node group.
and the nodes are rolling back to 1.21 with Ready, SchedulingDisabled which is not a good behaviour.
May I know what is the issue and what is the optimum ratio between PDB and update config in node group to avoid the errors mentioned above
The deployment/pod having PDB has 43 replicas